# Delete Repeated Characters without back-referencing with SED

Tags: linux, sed

Let's say we have a file that contains

```
HHEELLOO
HHYYPPOOTTHHEESSIISS
```

and we want to delete repeated characters. To my knowledge we can do this with

```
s/\([A-Z]\)\1/\1/g
```

This is a homework problem and the professor said he wants us to try the exercises without back-referencing or extended regular expressions. Is that possible on this one? I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: @Lucero If extended regular expressions are not turned on, it is necessary to escape the parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
s/AA/A/g
s/BB/B/g
...
s/ZZ/Z/g
```

As a one-liner:

```
sed 's/AA/A/g; s/BB/B/g; ...'
```

Comment: That's a long expression to handle both the upper-case and lower-case alphabet -- but I like your thought-provoking teaching instead of doing the homework.

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid of doing it that way because it seems like a long way of doing something super simple, but I suppose it's the only way with
the restrictions given.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasonable way to do this is to use the right tool for the job, in this case `tr`:

```
$ tr -s 'A-Z' < file
HELO
HYPOTHESIS
```

If you were going to use sed for that specific problem though then it'd just be:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)./\1/g' file
HELO
HYPOTHESIS
```

If that's not what you're looking for then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input and expected output.